# Nandroid backup/restore alternative(s)?

Tags: backup, restore, nandroid

I'm running Android 13 on a device for which there is no TWRP nor OrangeFox recovery module: it's a Pixel 7 Pro.

I'd like to perform the equivalent of nandroid backup/restore, and I'm wondering if there are any ways to do this.

To be clear, I'm not looking for any "backup" apps (*e.g.*, SwiftBackup, TitaniumBackup, *etc.*) which only back up apps and maybe call logs and messages. I want to be able to back up and restore all the OS partitions such as `/system`, `/boot`, *etc.*, which a working nandroid implementation can do.

I know that partitions can be backed up using `dd`-based methods, but if I take a `dd` backup, then upgrade my OS, and then decide that I want to return to the earlier OS, I can't use `dd` to restore, because the encryption would have changed.

Is there perhaps an EDL-based method for doing what I'd like to do?

Thank you in advance for any ideas and suggestions.

Comment: backup of partitions is useless because after factory reset there is no way to decrypt. Nandroid backup is dead

Comment: Thank you.   OK, so `dd` is out of the question. But what about my other suggestion: backup/restore via EDL mode?

Comment: **PS**: Nandroid backup isn't totally dead. There are a few implementations of TWRP and OrangeFox which still offer nandroid under Android 13 and 14 for a small number of devices.

Comment: I've seen but not used [this](https://github.com/Magisk-Modules-Alt-Repo/data backup) Magisk module that claims to do this. It's unfortunately archived but you can give it a try

Comment: Thank you. I've checked that out. It does take backups, but they can't be used for restore, unfortunately. When someone argued that backups without restore capabilities are useless, the developer said that even though normal restores are not possible using the app's backups, they can still be useful if you want to manually parse the backup file to extract apps or files or directories that have been present on the device.

Comment: what is the difference between partition dump made with dd and partition dump made with EDL? nothing. I still use TWRP too but my device isn't encrypted and I don't use apps that rely on keystore (or I am not aware of)